# Table view data not being displayed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have made a view controller with 2 views on it. On the top view, I have a table view inserted, with static cells and a basic cell. When I run the program, the data I entered manually onto the tableview does not get displayed.

My code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface CallTeacherViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topLayer;

@property  (nonatomic) CGFloat layerPosition;
```

View Controller.m

```
#import "CallTeacherViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface CallTeacherViewController ()

@end

@implementation CallTeacherViewController
@synthesize topLayer = _topLayer;
@synthesize layerPosition = _layerPosition;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 200;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    self.topLayer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1,0);
    self.topLayer.layer.shadowOpacity = .9;
    self.layerPosition = self.topLayer.frame.origin.x;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}

#define VIEW_HIDDEN 80

-(void) animateLayerToPoint:(CGFloat)x
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame = self.topLayer.frame;
                         frame.origin.x = x;
                         self.topLayer.frame = frame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         self.layerPosition =self.topLayer.frame.origin.x;                         
                     }];
}

- (IBAction)toggleLayer:(id)sender {
    if (self.layerPosition == VIEW_HIDDEN) {
        [self animateLayerToPoint:0];
    } else {
        [self animateLayerToPoint:VIEW_HIDDEN];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (self.layerPosition == VIEW_HIDDEN) {
        [self animateLayerToPoint:0];
    } else {
        [self animateLayerToPoint:0];
    }
}

- (IBAction)panLayer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)pan {
    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint point  = [pan translationInView:self.topLayer];
        CGRect frame = self.topLayer.frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.layerPosition + point.x;
        if (frame.origin.x < 0 ) frame.origin.x = 0;
        self.topLayer.frame = frame;
    }

    if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        if (self.topLayer.frame.origin.x <= 81) {
            [self animateLayerToPoint:0];
        } else {
            [self animateLayerToPoint: VIEW_HIDDEN];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;` to return a value > 0?

Furthermore did you set the TableView delegate & datasource to self?

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
    }

Comment: I don't know how to set the delegate and datasource to self

Comment: have you set text of static cell in storyboard?

Comment: yes I have, but it isn't displaying the text when run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have set the text for the static cell in the storyboard, you must remove this methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

if you set the static cell from storyboard you do not need these methods, as they decide on the storyboard: how many cells are and the text for each cell

**EDIT**:

if you want a tableView with static cell in UIViewController and your app is iOS 6+ you can:

Add UIContainerView in your UIVIewController and in container view you can put a UITableViewController with static cell

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ArmanPuri Are you subclassing `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController`?

Comment: @zLan oh i subclassing UITableViewController.. and not UIViewController like Arman .. i'll edit my answer

Comment: @llario Sorry that wasn't pointed towards you :). I believe his issue is using a static Table view on a `UIViewController` instead of an `UITableViewController`

Comment: @zLan you're right I have not seen good .. I'm editing my answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's populating your tableview with dynamic tableview content. See Ilario answer if you truly want static content through the storyboard.

//h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topLayer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

//m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // if you forget these two lines the methods below won't fire.
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    self.items = @[@"Foo", @"Bar", @"Test"]; // whatever data you need
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code under `TableViewController` class, works for me

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
        self.tableView.reloadData() 
    }
```